# Transition between portrait and landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, scrollview

For a new iPad app I have 2 different designs, one for landscape mode, and one for portrait mode.

The one in portrait mode basically consists of a scrollview with a grid of thumbs.

```
-----------------
|   O       O   |
|               |
|   O       O   |
|               |
|   O       O   |
-----------------

-----------------
|               |
|       O       |
|               |
|               |
|      ...      |
-----------------
```

In landscape mode this scrollview will become a scrollview with a Page Control, but I'm wondering on how to handle this properly.

Should I just use 1 scrollview and change it's properties when rotating?

How would you take care of this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two fairly different views with not a huge amount tying them together. It would be far easier to implement them using completely separate view controllers then swapping one out for the other when the interface rotates. This would also have the advantage of making the views far more reusable.

Unless you want a more complicated transition between the views (e.g. one of the thumbnails in portrait mode zooms out to become the large image in landscape mode) this is definitely the way I'd go.

Comment: Creating 2 different views was my first idea too, I don't think they will have any complicated transition, maybe just a simple fade in to ease the transition